# Modx - Collections: Get Selections paginated with pdoTools

Tags: pagination, modx, extras

How to output Selections children with pagination using pdoTools (pdoResources & pdoPage) and getSelections.
See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Collections comes with its own snippet for Selections: the getSelections, which is by default dependent on getResources.
If we want it to work with pdoTools and get paginated, we need to use pdoPage with &element=`getSelections` together with &getResourcesSnippet = `pdoResources`.

The code will look like this:

```
[[!pdoPage?
  &elementClass=`modSnippet`
  &element=`getSelections`
  &getResourcesSnippet = `pdoResources`
- other parameters
]]
```